# unlink delete files which are not links

Tags: files, rm, hard-link, ln

I created a hard link

```
$ ln hours.sh hours_link
```

test it

```
$ ls -l hours* 
-rw-r--r-- 2 me staff 653 Apr 12  2018 hours.sh
-rw-r--r-- 2 me staff 653 Apr 12  2018 hours_link
```

remove it with unlink

```
$ unlink hours_link
$ ls -l hours* 
-rw-r--r-- 1 me staff 653 Apr 12  2018 hours.sh
```

so far so good, but `unlink` can delete the original file which is not a link

```
$ cp hours.sh hours.bak.sh
$ unlink hours.sh
$ ls | grep hours.sh
#not return anything, hours.sh is deleted
```

check the manual and very surprised

```
   unlink - call the unlink function to remove the specified file
   rm - remove files or directories
```

If not just take it for granted, how should I understand this conversion?

Comment: Every file is a hardlink. There is no "original".

Comment: oh, I sort of feel discover a big secret. @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: Relevant: [What is the difference between a hard link and a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346425/108618)

Answer (score 3):

Every entry in a directory is a hard-link to the file. Both `rm` and `unlink` remove hard-links. A file is deleted when and only when, all hard-links to it are removed and no process has it open.

Therefore there is no difference (in form, just the name) between the original name and the name created with `ln`.