# A command to know if some file are "only" an hard link and "not" a symlink

Tags: files, symlink, command, hard-link

I need a command for an if condition to know if 'file_name' is an hard link (not symlink). Thanks

Comment: All files are hard links to themselves. Do you want to identify files with multiple links, or do you have an idea of an "original" file and other "links"?

Comment: I think that the question is duplicated, there is an already answered question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167610/determining-if-a-file-is-a-hard-link-or-symbolic-link

Comment: `[ -e file ] && [ \! -h file ]`

Answer (score 0):

***man test***

use -h to check, whether the file is symbolic link and the File exists.

```
   -h FILE
          FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -L)
```

.

```
bash-4.2$ ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 MYID MYID 0 Apr 26 14:37 test
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 MYID MYID 4 Apr 26 14:37 t -> test
bash-4.2$ [ -h t ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
bash-4.2$ [ -h test ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

Comment: `I need [...] to know if 'file_name' is [a] hard link (not symlink).` and you provide an answer to detect symlinks. I think this needs some explaining ....

Comment: @Bananguin This seems reasonable to me. Every file is a hard link, but only some are also of the specific "symbolic link" filetype. Could you elaborate your criticism?

Comment: @Kusalananda The OP is looking for a test for hard links and this answer, which is barely more than RTFM, highlights a test for sym links. This is especially not a test for hard links. The OP even explicitly states `(not symlink)` and receives an answer pertaining to precisely symlinks. You need to throw in additional technical knowledge to explain your "seems reasonable" judgement. Notice: this demo says "no" when it detects a hard link. I am not saying the technical background is wrong. I am saying this is a bad answer.

Comment: @Bananguin Both Kamaraj and I interpreted the question as asking for a way to detect whether a file was a hard link and not a symbolic link (see title). With that interpretation, the answer seems reasonable. If the question was to "detect whether a file was a hard link or not (not whether it was a symbolic link or not)", I can definitely see that your argument is totally valid. The question would then also need additional clarification as to what they meant by that.

Comment: @Kusalananda `[ -h /@/not-there ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"` => `no`. So I guess that `/@/not-there` is *only* a hard link?

Comment: @mosvy I was carefully using the word "reasonable". I did not use the word "correct".

Comment: @Kusalananda I concur, that the OP is looking for `a way to detect whether a file was a hard link`. This answer provides a way to detect SYMlinks and nothing else. The example at the bottom literally say `yes` in case of a symlink and `no` otherwise. Otherwise is not equivalent to "this is a hard link". The question for something about hardlinks gets an answer which is strictly about symlinks. The answer is strictly about symlinks while the OP asks for hardlinks. There is a difference there. That is why I think an explanation is needed. The answer is not off topic, but bad without explanation.